# Почему mysql просит доп. пакеты?

Tags: mysql

Команда

```
mysqld -u user -p
```

Ответ:

> The program 'mysqld' can be found in the following packages: 
>   mysql-server-core-5.5  mariadb-server-core-5.5  mysql-server-core-5.6
>   percona-xtradb-cluster-server-5.5 Ask your administrator to install
>   one of them

Я не понимаю что он хочет от меня, как список процессов посмотреть что бы убить нужный?

Comment: Он хочет что бы вы установили один из необходимых ему пакетов.

Comment: @socode всё ж работает, зачем мне ещё что-то ставить?

Comment: Как же у тебя "всё работает", если mysqld не работает (тупо так по причине его отсутствия)? И где тут "тяжёлый запрос"?

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что 1) заданный вопрос не соответствует имеющимся фактам; 2) заголовок вопроса не соответствует содержанию.

Comment: @Akina каким например фактам он не соответствует? Заголовок переименовал

Comment: Потому что у вас MySQL-сервер ничего не просит. **Его просто нет.** Система (скорее всего хук command-not-found в баше) прямо предлагает вам какой-нибудь поставить и перечисляет пакеты, в которых он содержится.

Comment: Просит не MySQL. Просит операционная система. В переводе на русский её сообщение звучит приблизительно как `Ну нету у меня гармошки!`